# I can't seem to get my Gridview to update to my SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, gridview

Here is my current code behind for the `OnRowUpdating` event and SQL statement to update the database. It is throwing an exception:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.error

Code:

```
protected void GV_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtSu = (TextBox)GV.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtBox1"); // each textbox refers to the Am then Pm day
    TextBox txtSu1 = (TextBox)GV.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtBox2");// sun pm
    TextBox txtMo = (TextBox)GV.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtBox3");// mon am
    TextBox txtMo1 = (TextBox)GV.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtBox4");//mon pm
    TextBox txtTu = (TextBox)GV.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtBox5");
    TextBox txtTu1 = (TextBox)GV.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtBox6");
    TextBox txtWe = (TextBox)GV.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtBox7");
    TextBox txtWe1 = (TextBox)GV.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtBox8");
    TextBox txtTh = (TextBox)GV.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtBox9");
    TextBox txtTh1 = (TextBox)GV.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtBox10");
    TextBox txtFr = (TextBox)GV.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtBox11");
    TextBox txtFr1 = (TextBox)GV.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtBox12");
    TextBox txtSa = (TextBox)GV.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtBox13");
    TextBox txtSa1 = (TextBox)GV.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtBox14");

    string sql = "UPDATE tblEMPLOYEE SET EmployeeID=@ID, " +
                                     "AvailSun=@AvSu, " +
                                     "AvailSun1=@AvSu1, " +
                                     "AvailMon=@AvMo, " +
                                     "AvailMon1=@AvMo1, " +
                                     "AvailTues=@AvTu, " +
                                     "AvailTues1=@AvTu1, " +
                                     "AvailWedn=@AvWe, " +
                                     "AvailWedn1=@AvWe1, " +
                                     "AvailThurs=@AvTh, " +
                                     "AvailThurs1=@AvTh1, " +
                                     "AvailFri=@AvFr, " +
                                     "AvailFri1=@AvFr1, " +
                                     "AvailSat=@AvSa, " +
                                     "AvailSat1=@AvSa1 " +
                                     "WHERE EmployeeID=@ID";
    CMethods.executeNonQuery(sql, "@ID", txtID.Text, "@AvSu", txtSu.Text, "@AvSu1", txtSu1.Text, "@AvMo", txtMo.Text, "@AvMo1", txtMo1.Text, "@AvTu", txtTu.Text, "@AvTu1", txtTu1.Text, "@AvWe", txtWe.Text, "@AvWe1", txtWe1.Text, "@AvTh", txtTh.Text, "@AvTh1", txtTh1.Text, "@AvFr", txtFr.Text, "@AvFr1", txtFr1.Text, "@AvSa", txtSa.Text, "@AvSa1", txtSa1.Text, "@ID", ID);
    GV.EditIndex = -1;
    fillUsers();
}
private void fillUsers()
{
    GV.DataSource = CMethods.returnTable("SELECT * FROM tblEMPLOYEE WHERE EmployeeID=" + lblEmployee.Text);
    GV.DataBind();
}
```

In Cmethods

```
public static class CMethods
{
    public static DataTable returnTable(String CommandText, params Object[] values)
    {
        SqlConnection con =
        new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Provider"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CommandText, con);
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i += 2)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue((String)values[i], values[i + 1]);
        }
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds, "tbl");
        return ds.Tables["tbl"];
    }

public static bool executeNonQuery(String CommandText, params Object[] values)
{
    bool bln = true;
    SqlConnection con =
    new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Provider"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CommandText, con);
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i += 2)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue((String)values[i], values[i + 1]);
    }
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        bln = false;

    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
    return bln;
}
 public static double returnValue(string str)
{
    double dblTemp = 0.0D;
    string strTemp = String.Empty;
    bool blnFirstDec = false;
    bool blnFirstNeg = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        if (str.Substring(i, 1) == "-")
        {
            blnFirstNeg = true;
        }
        if (IsNumeric(str.Substring(i, 1)) || str.Substring(i, 1) == ".")
        {
            if (str.Substring(i, 1) == ".")
            {
                if (!blnFirstDec)
                {
                    blnFirstDec = true;
                    strTemp += ".";
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                strTemp += str.Substring(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are not showing all parts to your code. For example we don't know what CMethods is or what fillUsers() do? Also, that way you use the executeNonQuery is uncommon. It is hard to guess what is wrong from what you've shown.

Comment: The important part is how your `CMethods.executeNonQuery` method operates.  Include that in your question please.

Comment: And please also tell **WHERE EXACTLY** (what line of code) this exception happens.....

Comment: The exception has been fixed now my gridview will not update but it will not throw an error i'm not sure if its my SQL statement or what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FindControl control may not return control if you not provide correct control id

for example you have given `txtBo13`(missing `x`) but actually you may have `txtBox13`,

so below code return null for `txtSa`

```
TextBox txtSa = (TextBox)GV.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtBo13");
```

when you call `Text` property of `txtSa` you will get `NullReferenceException`

if you have given id as `txtBox13`, change the code accordingly

```
TextBox txtSa = (TextBox)GV.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtBox13");
```

And also you may have forgot to set `@student` parameter value

Comment: Thank you that did rid me of the NullReferenceException error and my code now runs without error but now when i hit Update the values for the textbox I edit in my gridview do not update I'll post back with some more code

Comment: @user3064123 you forgot to send `@student` parameter to the `executeNonQuery` method

Comment: I just changed that to EmployeeID as it was the incorrect name i'll update the code here too but it isn't necessary to send the ID because I haven't made that item editable I'm only using it to tell the Database where to update in my sql statement does it need to be in the command string regarless?

Comment: Where condition should return `true` for update the records, so you need to send ID parameter like `"@ID", lblEmployee.Text`